# How to obtain the "top N%" number for tags of a user via API?

Tags: support, tags, flair, api

Here's [what my Stack Overflow Developer Story shows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/901944?tab=topactivity#form-section-TechStack):

[image: dev story]

And my profile:

[image: profile]

I want to obtain these top percentages via API for my personal website.

I've tried the `/users/{id}/top-tags` endpoint, it gives info like this:

```
{
  "user_id": 901944,
  "answer_count": 166,
  "answer_score": 532,
  "question_count": 11,
  "question_score": 41,
  "tag_name": "sass"
},
```

As for the user endpoint, it also provides neither the top percentage nor rank.

At worst, I would use an image, but the [Flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair) section doesn't provide such data.

Comment: Define "Top N%".  For example, is this just considering User's scores, or is it comparing the user to other users in the same tag (in which case the sample picture seems unlikely).  Define *exactly* how you would compute this in pseudo code.

Comment: I don't know! I just want to show the same number that StackOverflow already shows on my Developer Story page.

Comment: That clarifies it, thanks. Unfortunately, it also makes the API solution way more complicated. :)

Comment: I also updated the question with a different top percentage example.

Comment: The way those scores are calculated for Dev Story is probably a direct SQL query. `SELECT SUM(p.Score) / COUNT(*) AS [ScorePerPost] FROM Posts AS p GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId ORDER BY SUM(p.Score) / COUNT(*);` I doubt that's available in the API.

Comment: So shouldn't this be on Stack Apps?

Comment: @StephenLeppik, yes. But people noticed that they get more upvotes here and such questions don't often get closed or migrated to Stack Apps.  So we have 2 sites dedicated to the API. :)

Comment: Also, this site has an active `api` tag.